# Mudar padding de um painel X quando adiciono classe em um painel Y (ambos do mesmo painel pai)

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

Boa noite meu povo,

Tenho uma tela onde tenho uma sidebar no lado esquerdo. Quando defino ela com a classe CSS .modoCompacto ela fica com 50 pixels de largura, ajustando os botões e layout. Quando coloco a classe .modoExpandido ela fica no tamanho comum. Meu painel root é um AnchorPane, assim consigo deixar os botões expansíveis com no modo compacto como no código a seguir:

```
#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda {
    -fx-background-color: #222;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px;
    -fx-background-radius: 0px;
    -fx-padding: 0px;
    -fx-spacing: 14px;
}

#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda #PainelTitulo .label {
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-graphic-text-gap: 14px;
    -fx-max-width: Infinity;
    -fx-padding: 14px;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFF;
}

#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda #PainelTitulo .button {
    -fx-content-display: GRAPHIC_ONLY;
}

#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda #ListaOpcoes {
    -fx-spacing: 7px;
}

#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda #ListaOpcoes .button, #PainelMenuEsquerda #PainelTitulo .button {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px;
    -fx-background-radius: 0px;
    -fx-cursor: HAND;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-max-width: Infinity;
    -fx-padding: 14px 17.5px 14px 14px;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFF;
}

#PainelRoot #PainelMenuEsquerda #ListaOpcoes .button:hover, #PainelMenuEsquerda #PainelTitulo .button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #3399FF99;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto {
    -fx-padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoExpandido {
    -fx-padding: 0px 0px 0px 224px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoExpandido #ListaOpcoes .button {
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
    -fx-graphic-text-gap: 14px;
    -fx-pref-width: 224px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto, .modoCompacto #PainelTitulo .button {
    -fx-max-width: 50px;
    -fx-min-width: 50px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto #PainelTitulo {
    -fx-max-width: 224px;
    -fx-min-width: 224px;
    -fx-rotate: -270.0;
    -fx-translate-x: -87px;
    -fx-translate-y: -87px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto #PainelTitulo .button {
    -fx-rotate: -90.0;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto #PainelTitulo .button .image-view, .modoCompacto #ListaOpcoes .button .image-view {
    -fx-translate-x: 3.5;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto #ListaOpcoes .button {
    -fx-content-display: GRAPHIC_ONLY;
    -fx-graphic-text-gap: 35px;
}

#PainelRoot .modoCompacto #ListaOpcoes .button:hover {
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
    -fx-min-width: 224px;
}
```

Agora vamos ao que eu preciso.

Quando eu adicionar a classe .modoCompacto no PainelMenuLateral queria que o PainelContainer tivesse um padding personalizado. Qual seria a sintaxe para fazer isso de forma mais aproveitosa? Queria que quando adicionasse essa classe na sidebar ele ja mudasse o PainelContainer. Ambos são do mesmo painel pai PainelRoot.

Comment: Se for o que estou pensando que você está tentando fazer, você pode usar js para adicionar uma class que ficaria responsável pelo padding. `$(".classe").click(function({$(".painel").addClass("mudapadding");});`

Comment: Adicione o html à sua pergunta.

Comment: Michel Douglas coloca o HTML da sua página e o CSS completo que fica mais fácil para te dar uma resposta precisa. Talvez apenas com CSS de para resolver isso!

Comment: Galera, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas por favor mais atenção. Se trata de um FXML, JavaFX